# AWS How can I implement check back questions for my Amazon Lex Bot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Currently I have many intent questions and lambda functions which answer those user questions by taking answers out of my DynamoDB. Now there are some answers which require a back questions to the user e.g. user asks "How are you", Lex Bot answers "I am fine. How are you", user answers "I am fine, too". Now Lex Bot should actually recognize that the user answered his question and should say something like "Cool" or "Very nice".

Is there some possibility to implement such a back-answer-handling?

I don't want to have some intent saying "I am fine, too" as this is really ugly and would not always be fitting :/

**Edit: If something is unclear in my question, please just ask me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initially call your Lambda in the initialisation and validation phase, and return the the Lex response with a DialogAction of ElicitSlot, so you can then pick up the second response ?